# gulp + browser-sync - why gulp errors on removing directory from app?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

In a simple gulp + browser-sync project [here](https://github.com/abhishekisnot/AngularDemo), all file add/delete/change are working correctly, but when I delete a directory from app gulp/browser-sync throws an error like below:

`events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: watch EPERM
    at errnoException (fs.js:1030:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1048:26)`

I am not sure where to look for possible problems. If someone can point me to correct direction.

Comment: Can you update to 1.9.0 and let me know if this is still an issue

Comment: Upgrading to latest version solved the problem. Please add it as answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was an outdated version of BrowserSync.

Updating to the latest version will solve this issue.